# Sublime Text 2 Font-Family Menu

Tags: css, sublimetext2, font-family

I'm looking for a solution for a context menu which lists basic font-families, aside from the absolute bare bones listings. I tried installing the CSSFontFamily package, *it's not changing the default dialog; just the same base fonts (cursive, monaco, sans-serif etc). Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks~B

(I just asked this question on the Sublime Forum. But the forum navigation wasn't working properly, so I'm coming back to my first choice for questions/solutions)

Comment: What do you mean when you say *"it doesn't seem to be working"*? Do you get any errors? What output, if any, do you see? Please [edit] your question to be more specific.

Comment: I don't see the edit info so I'd like to put forth my rationale for wording the question the way I did: *I originally wrote that "it doesn't seem to be working" because the package may not be working because I'm not using it properly or I failed to change a setting. I feel I owe the package author the benefit of the doubt before I say it's just not working. Perhaps the lack of specificity wasn't worth that consideration in the broader context. Hope the revision is more useful...